# how to put particular application on system startup in fedora 15?

Tags: fedora, login

How do I put particular application on system startup on my Fedora 15.

For instance if I want to start my Firefox browser on system startup how do I achieve this?

What have I done so far is, I just created a simple shell scrip and put the command of starting a Firefox browser in that and placed that shell script in `/etc/init.d/` directory.

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/firefox
```

Comment: Firefox isn't something you can start on system startup, it's something you start after you've logged in, as part of your user session startup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That should be configured in your desktop environment (DE) settings. For example if you're running Gnome, use `gnome-session-properties` as explained in [this question](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/question/277/gui-to-configure-startup-applications-in-f16) on AskFedora.

For KDE this can be configured in `Autostart`, which looks like this:

[image]

The reason why the global init scripts won't work is that these commands are run outside the scope of the GUI/DE. Similarly, you can't run `firefox` from a plain tty shell without tweaks, but you can from the terminal window within your DE.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways you can do this. The first way is for if you are running gnome.
From the terminal type the command

```
#gnome-session-properties
```

and ENTER then you can add your entry there...

for example :
empathy is in /usr/bin/empathy

Or you can create a script and place it /etc/rc.local/myautostart.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
/usr/bin/empathy
```

Make the script file executable

```
#chmod r+x /etc/rc.local/myautostart.sh
```

And there you have it